# bad operand type for abs(): 'list'

Tags: python, numpy

When calculating the absolute value in each value of an array, I am getting an error related to bad operand type for abs(): 'list'. The part of source code which is failing is the next:

```
x = amplitudex * sin((2 * pi * (frequency * 1) * t) + phase);
y = amplitudey * sin((2 * pi * (frequency * 2) * t) + phase);
z = amplitudez * sin((2 * pi * (frequency * 3) * t) + phase);

w=  0.55* (x + y + z);
....
n = len(w);
wf = [float(0)] * n;
for k in range(n):  # For each output element
    s = float(0);
    for t in range(n):  # For each input element
        s += w[t] * cmath.exp(-2j * cmath.pi * t * k / n);
    wf[k] = float(s);

sf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*numCycles), numSamples/2);

#The calculation of absolute values causes error:
plot(sf, 2.0/numSamples * abs(wf[0:100]));
```

How can I fix this error in abs function? I got confused with this error :(

Thanks

Comment: Because `abs` could not be casted to a list

Comment: use `map` in order to apply abs to each element in your array

Comment: You can end statements with just a newline, without `;`.

Comment: use vectorized abs - `np.abs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather that you want `abs` applied to each member of the list slice along with some other computation, since you use slice notation. That's easy with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
plot(sf, [2.0/numSamples * abs(element) for element in wf[0:100]]);
```

Answer (score 9):

I see you've already imported numpy because you're using `np.linspace` in the code.  You are probably confusing numpy's abs, which will happily work on lists and arrays, with `__builtin__.abs`, which only works for scalars.

Change this:

```
abs(wf[0:100])
```

To this:

```
np.abs(wf[0:100])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because `abs` could not be used for `list`. You could use it with map:

```
map(abs, wf[0:100])
```

In case you are using Python 3 add `list`:

```
list(map(abs, wf[0:100]))
```

Or you could use `list comprehension` to set your abs_list:

```
wf_abs = [abs(x) for x in wf[0:100]]
```