# TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'

Tags: python, scipy, signals

The following simple code returns: TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'

```
from scipy.signal import residue

def x_filter():
    p = [complex(-2505.707527665261,3165.104073896715),complex(-2505.707527665261,-3165.104073896715),complex(-3449.516723926777,1032.914743287806),complex(-3449.516723926777,-1032.914743287806)]
    r = [complex(-1981.17378001573,2672.79673635191),complex(-1981.17378001573,-2672.79673635191),complex(1981.17378001573,-10000.37025226017),complex(1981.17378001573,10000.37025226017)]
    k = []

    [b,a]=residue(r,p,k)

filtered = x_filter()
```

I replaced p and r with:

```
p = [-2505.707527665261+3165.104073896715j,-2505.707527665261-3165.104073896715j,-3449.516723926777+1032.914743287806j,-3449.516723926777-1032.914743287806j]
r = [-1981.17378001573+2672.79673635191j,-1981.17378001573-2672.79673635191j,1981.17378001573-10000.37025226017j,1981.17378001573+10000.37025226017j]
```

..., but makes no difference.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there any workaround?

I referred to [bad operand type for abs(): 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956761/bad-operand-type-for-abs-list), but I cannot apply that solution because the __builtin__.abs() function is used in scipy.signal.residue (not in my code).

Comment: Why are you trying to pass lists in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.residue.html), it seems that you mistook inputs for outputs. `residue` takes *a* and *b* and returns *r*, *p* and *k*.

Third parameter (*tol*) should be a number but you are passing a list.

---

You might be using wrong method. Take a look at [scipy.signal.invres](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.invres.html#scipy.signal.invres), that should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, I see! I'm so embarrassed ... Yes, scipy.signal.invres is what I was looking for. Thank you very much for telling me.

Comment: Thanks again and let me make an excuse. I made such a mistake because residue() in MATLAB can do both ways, `[r,p,k] = residue(b,a)` as well as `[b,a] = residue(r,p,k)`. So, I mixed them up.